# Check whether a number lies between two other numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason my code won't return False EVER and I cant figure it out?

I think the issue is with how my `between` function is written but it makes sense to me. Also I am struggling to get my restart function to work. If somebody could help me with those 2 areas I would be extremely grateful.

```
def between(a,b,c):
   if a>b and b<c:
      Rnum =True
   else:
      Rnum=False

def main(): #main function need in all programs for automated testing
    print ("This program will ask the user for 3 numbers and determine if 
    the second number lies betweenthe first and the third")
    print()

    while True:
       numone=input('Please enter the first number - the low number:')
       if numone.isdigit():
           numone=int(numone)
           break
       else:
           print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')


    while True:
       numtwo=input('Please enter the second number - the test number:  ')
       if numtwo.isdigit():
           numtwo=int(numtwo)
           break
       else:
           print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')

    while True:
       numthree=input('Please enter the third number - the high number:')
       if numthree.isdigit():
           numthree=int(numthree)
           break
       else:
            print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')
            sprint()

    number =between(numone,numtwo,numthree)
    print('The statement ' +  str(numone)  + ' lies between '   +  str(numtwo)  +  ' and ' +  str(numthree) + ' is True.'"\n")

    #Restart question
    while True:
        restart = input('Would you like to play again (Y/N)? ')
        if restart == 'Y' or restart == 'y':
            print('Restarting!' + ('\n' * 2))
            break
        if restart == 'N' or restart == 'n':
            print('Thank you for playing.' + ('\n' *2))
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid response. Please answer with a 'Y' or 'N'")
        if restart == 'N' or restart == 'n':
            break
        else:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    main()  #excucte main function
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/   You'd better read the site guidelines to understand how to ask a proper question here

Comment: Your between function is wrong. It's asking if b is smaller than both a and c

Comment: Which one is supposed to be the inbetween, it looks like b from the function, but numone in the calling code. Perhaps this is why you should document the parameters.

Comment: I changed the statement to actually make sense lol 
def between(a,b,c):
   if a<b and b<c:
      Rnum =True
   else:
      Rnum=False

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: this time it returned that the first input was between the 2nd and 3rd input which is not only not true but it should only be returning the 2nd and true or false.

>Please enter the first number - the low number:5
>Please enter the second number - the test number:  15
>Please enter the third number - the high number:20
>The statement 5 lies between 15 and 20 is True.

>Would you like to play again (Y/N)? Y
>Restarting!


>>>

Comment: I fixed everything so far except the restart now thanks to you guys. any ideas on the restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of your `between` function was slightly wrong (I've rename the variables to make it slightly clearer). In addition, you were not `returning` the value of the function so it was basically doing nothing. You were also *always* printing "True".

I have modified your code to `return` the result of the `between` function. I have made the result of this function a variable called `true_or_false` which is then printed at the end of each game.

In order to get your code to loop, all you need is another `while` loop which you can break out of if the user does not want to continue.

```
def between(low,test,high):
    if low < test < high:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main(): #main function need in all programs for automated testing
    print ("This program will ask the user for 3 numbers and determine if\nthe second number lies betweenthe first and the third")

    while True:
        while True:
           numone=input('\nPlease enter the first number - the low number:')
           if numone.isdigit():
               numone=int(numone)
               break
           else:
               print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')

        while True:
           numtwo=input('Please enter the second number - the test number:  ')
           if numtwo.isdigit():
               numtwo=int(numtwo)
               break
           else:
               print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')

        while True:
           numthree=input('Please enter the third number - the high number:')
           if numthree.isdigit():
               numthree=int(numthree)
               break
           else:
                print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.')

        true_or_false =between(numone,numtwo,numthree)
        print('The statement ' +  str(numtwo)  + ' lies between '   +  str(numone)  +  ' and ' +  str(numthree) + ' is ' + str(true_or_false) + "\n")

        restart = ""
        while restart.upper() != "Y":

            restart = input('Would you like to play again (Y/N)? ')
            if restart.upper() == "Y":
                print('Restarting!')

            elif restart.upper() == "N":
                print ('Thank you for playing.')
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. Please answer with a 'Y' or 'N'")


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()  #excucte main function
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed everything...how does it seem so clear when you put it this way? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Xaneph No problem :) don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It is important to note that Python values _readability_. The simplier your code is, the better it will be (and it is much easier for someone else to read/fix bugs)

Comment: I modified your code to ask another question. We needed input validation for the restart and I like the way you wrote the restart better with the .upper but I couldnt get that to work with the input validation in case anything but Y/N was entered. Any thoughts on how to modify yours to get that to work? For what its worth the code that I wrote out for the restart does work I was just curious.

Comment: my mod was rejected but I dont know how to get code to appear in the comments when I only have 500 characters lol noob here

Comment: That works great thank you. This will streamline my programs moving forward as well

Answer (score 1):

You have small mistake, either in the problem definition or in the example code. Anyways if you modify it a bit:

```
def between(a,b,c): if b>a and b<c: return 'True'
else: return 'False'

 print('The statement ' +  str(numtwo)  + ' lies between '   
+  str(numone)  +  ' and ' +  str(numthree) + ' is ' +
between(a,b,c) +"\n")
```